# How to optimize this groupby statement in PySpark to avoid bufferholder error (shuffle block size > 2GB)?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark statement that works okay if the data for each user I am working on is small (<2GB), but if one of the users' data exceeds 2GB (did not consider it in the design), my job fails. I have tried repartitioning, increasing memory, but all to no success. I was hoping if someone could help me figure this statement out to ensure that we have 'null' in the 'proxy' column if the struct size is greater than 2GB.

Sample code:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.dropDuplicates(subset=columns) \
                .select(F.col(group_column).alias("uid"), F.lit(view).alias(
                "orientation"), F.struct("*").alias("proxy")) \
                .groupby("uid", "orientation") \
                .agg(F.create_map("orientation", F.collect_list("proxy")).alias(view + "_proxy")) \
                .select("uid", view + "_proxy")
```

The problem happens when we perform `F.struct("*")` and if the data associated with a single user exceed 2GB.

Comment: Clearly there is skew in your data, adding additional column (which can act as tiebreaker or distribute data further) will help. In your case since you are doing a group by and there is skew in data, even though you repartition or increase memory it doesn't help as ultimately during the shuffle operation, data with same keys will end up in a single executor.

Comment: If you know the average payload size in the 'proxy' field, then can you just take 2GB / avg. payload size.   That is the number of rows you can safely process per 'uid' and 'orientation'.  So basically just filter out all 'uid'/'orientation' combos with row count > (2 GB / avg. payload).

Comment: I am used to write Spark in Scala,but as I understand from you code `collect_list` may result in this issue. If you need just all distinct ones use `collect_map`, this can reduce space.